# Create a model in android dynamically from rest client

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, model-view-controller

I have created an android app with product as one table and items as another table .As an eg., if wheels is an product, then wood , rubber and plastic wheels are items.

Now  I am stuck in a situation where the client will add another product named belts and multiple items in product `{belts}` in php. I am using REST to get response.

Based on the response I already have model class for Product so no problem and I can save the items `{ belt}`  in database , but how to create a POJO class for dynamically created Item under `product{belt}` with different column name. If model class creation is not possible dynamically ,how to fetch data without model class.

Comment: Your question is discriptive. Why don't you support it more with some sample code snippets so that it's easier to understand your approach?

Comment: thankzz for reply man..just simple question to make u clear. can i create a model(POJO) class dynamically based on the user input.??? .i know i can create a database table dynamically..but i can't use it in controller as i cant create a model class on dynamic client input..

Answer (score 2):

Thank you every one for your response.
After some research on various sites. Finally I have found a proper solution with code from this site..It uses jsonschema2pojo library..

https://dzone.com/articles/converting-json-to-pojos-using-java?edition=304112&utm_source=Daily%20Digest&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=dd%202017-06-01

Answer (score 0):

Model Class creation is possible imho when you use scripting languages such as JavaScript(Since objects in JS can be created dynamically) but it will be quite hard. I doubt it is possible in compiled languages like Java but you can use template classes to reach a semi like behavior.

If you want to parse data(not sure how you define fetch) without using models you can use this library in Android.
https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: thank u for suggestion..ya i am able to receive it with jsonObject..As you know  using it key values to fetch data in controllers is very much complex..that's y i am looking for a way to create model dynamically..!

Comment: If any other options available..plz let me know...@bumblebeen

Comment: @monuc, JDXA ORM can persist JSON objects in an SQLite database. Check some code snippets here (http://softwaretree.com/v1/products/jdxa/Mapping-JSON-Objects.html ). JDXA can also handle relationships in JSON objects. In your case, you would have to define mappings for the Product and the Item classes. Disclaimer: I am the architect of JDXA ORM.